# Insert jTable Vector data into MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, insert, jtable

Can i insert a jTable vector data into MSSQL through JDBC in some easy fashion? Like just send the entire vector in an insert statement to the JDBC for insertion?

```
// Get all the table data
DefaultTableModel mtableSearch = (DefaultTableModel) tableSearch.getModel();

Vector data = mtableSearch.getDataVector();
```

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache [DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbutils/QueryRunner.html) would be a good place to start. Look at QueryRunner.batch(). You'll need to convert the Vector of Vectors from getDataVector to an `Object[][]`.